# Explicitly reconstruct conformal mapping from conformal factor

Tags: differential-geometry, conformal-geometry

Consider two smooth, compact surfaces $\mathcal{S_i} \subset \mathbb{R}^3$, with Riemannian metrics $g_i$, $i=1,2$ and a conformal mapping $f:S_1\rightarrow S_2$.

Suppose we know the conformal factor $u$, namely $g_2 = e^{2u} g_1$. Is that information enough to *explicitly* give the mapping of the embedding of $\mathcal{S_1}$ to corresponding points of the embedding of $\mathcal{S_2}$?

Comment: With the current formulation, $S_1=S_2$ and, hence, you can take $f$ to be the identity map. Did you want to ask something else?

Comment: Thanks, I have corrected it

Comment: This still makes no sense. At the very least, you want $g_2=e^{2u}f^*(g_1)$. Then you are asking to construct an explicit isometry of two Riemannian surfaces $(S_1, e^{-2u}g_2)$ and $(S_1, g_1)$. I do not believe there is an explicit formula for this, even if $S_1, S_2$ are given by some polynomial equations (even if you know a value $f(p)=q$ as well as the value of $df(p)$, solving this problem amounts to solving some complicated differential equation). At best, you can get an algorithm constructing an approximation to such an isometry.